# Dots not appearing when overflowing

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

I have a table with the middle cell containing long text.
I found the CSS below which theoretically should prevent the text from overflowing and add some dots at the end. It does prevent it from overflowing, HOWEVER there's no dots. Could you help me out understanding why please?

I would like it to be like this: long tex...

```css
.headlinesStyle {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  white-space: normal;
  color: transparent !important;
}

.headlinesStyle::selection {
  color: transparent !important;
}

.headlinesStyle:before {
  content: attr(data-cutwrap);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>short text</td>
    <td><span class='headlinesStyle'><a href="http...">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </a></span></td>
    <td>short</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `white-space` and `text-overflow` like this:

```
.dots {
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: black; //if you want to color the dots
}


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>short text</td>
    <td class="dots"><a href="http...">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT </a></td>
    <td>short</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o24b6w0u/2/

Answer (score 0):

Please add following styles to your code..

```css
a {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>short text</td>
    <td><a href="http...">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </a></span>
    </td>
    <td>short</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Additionally if you are having a span to achieve ellipsis you don't need it. Simple apply styles to anchor tag directly

Answer (score 0):

```css
.headlinesStyle {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 18px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 15%;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #333 !important;
}

.headlinesStyle::selection {
  color: transparent !important;
}

.headlinesStyle:before {
  content: attr(data-cutwrap);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>short text</td>
    <td><span class='headlinesStyle'><a href="http...">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </a></span></td>
    <td>short</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
.headlinesStyle {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 18px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.headlinesStyle::selection {
  color: transparent !important;
}

.headlinesStyle:before {
  content: attr(data-cutwrap);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>short text</td>
    <td><span class='headlinesStyle'><a href="http...">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT </a></span></td>
    <td>short</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```